# Network devices undiscoverable for 578 seconds when connecting to wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I've had this issue that has plagued me for years and now I'm finally annoyed enough to ask for help. The crux of the issue is that when I connect to to the wifi network it takes approximately 578 seconds before ping returns a successful packet to one of the connected devices, i.e a NAS drive. I've somewhat troubleshooted it and have a suspicion but can't work out how to analyse, prove or fix the issue.

The set up is:

1. TP LINK Archer Router (192.168.0.1) broadcasting wifi
2. Netgear PWL1000 Powerline (192.168.0.101) broadcasting wifi and connected to the TP LINK router (192.168.0.1) via powerline.

Example devices are:

1. MacBook (192.168.0.2) connected to TP LINK via wifi
2. NAS drive (192.168.0.3) connected to TP LINK via ethernet
3. RaspberryPi (192.168.0.102) connected to the Powerline wifi
4. iPhone (192.168.0.4) connected to TP link via wifi

Here is what I've discovered through trial and error:

1. When MacBook connects to TP LINK over wifi it takes 578 seconds before the NAS, iPhone & RaspberryPi return pings
2. If MacBook disconnects from TP LINK wifi and reconnects it takes another 578 seconds before devices return pings
3. When MacBook connects to Powerline, NAS, iPhone RaspberryPi return pings **immediately**
4. If MacBook disconnects from Powerline and reconnects devices return pings **immediately**.
5. If Powerline is removed from the network and turned off then when MacBook is connected to TP LINK via wifi NAS and iPhone return pings **immediately**.
6. If Powerlines is reintroduced to the network then when MacBook is connected to TP LINK devices continue to return pings.
7. If TP LINK is restarted then the problem returns and devices don't ping for 578 seconds.

It's as if the Powerline is hijacking the TP Links DHCP (I think) and is causing the delay although I don't fully understand DHCP other than it is what delegates ip addresses. Unfortunately the administration interface for the Powerline doesn't give options for DHCP but I assume it provides this services as it assigns IP address to connected devices.

If anyone could help shed some light on this or point me to tools to help analyse this it would be very much appreciated. The goal here is that when connecting to the TP LINK Router the devices can be accessed close to immediately.

Thanks!

Comment: if both of those wifi devices are set up as routers with DHCP, that probably is the issue - you probably want one of those devices to be set up as a so called "dumb AP"

Comment: I had a Powerline device in the past and it didn’t support DHCP, and even if yours did support it, this problem wouldn’t auto resolve after 568 seconds it would be ongoing to infinite. If you still believe it’s caused by DHCP, then changing the DHCP subnet on the router, will solve your problem if it doesn’t resolve the problem it’s trivial to revert

Comment: Try updating the firmware on your routers.  Try new powerline adapters.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the Powerline last night and found it had DHCP On but not method to turn it off. I set the IP address manually which then set DHCP to off and have set the subnet mask to 255.255.254.0 on the Powerline which differs from the router (255.255.255.0). I'll see if this has any effect tonight. @John Firmware on both are up to date. Spending another hundred or so on a new powerline without knowing why could simply result in the same issue.